# Rotating 3D mobjects without moving the camera - Manim

Tags: python, 3d, rotation, cube, manim

So I'm having this code :

```
class Intro(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        config.background_color = rgb_to_color(hex_to_rgb("#141414"))
        sq = Square().shift(LEFT)
        cu = Cube().shift(RIGHT)

        VGroup(sq, cu).arrange(RIGHT, buff=2)

        self.play(Write(sq), Write(cu), run_time=2)
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Rotate(cu, angle=PI, rate_func=linear))
        self.wait(2)
```

I want to rotate the cube around it's Y axis, this way :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSNtp.png
I know how to do that with the camera moving but I don't want the camera to move. is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the answer myself. you should use the Rotating() function and give it an axis. in my case the UP axis worked for me.